# Returning generator from a function

Tags: python, function, generator

I'm slowly getting to wrap my head around Python generators.

While it's not a real life problem for now, I'm still wondering why I can't return a generator from a function.

When I define a function with `yield`, it acts as a generator.  But if I define it *inside* another function and try to return that instead, I get an ordinary function, i.e. not a generator with `next` method.

In other words, why the `give_gen()` approach in code below does not work?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

def gen(d):
    n = 0
    while True:
        n = n + d
        time.sleep(0.5)
        yield n

def give_gen(d):
    def fn():
        n = 0
        while True:
            n = n + d
            time.sleep(0.5)
            yield n
    return fn

if __name__ == '__main__':

    g = give_gen(3)     # does not work
    g = gen(3)          # works well

    while True:
        print g.next()
        # AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'next'
        # in case of give_gen
```

Why can't I return a generator from a function?

Answer (score 7):

A generator function returns a generator *only when called*. Call `fn` to create the generator object:

```
return fn()
```

or call the returned object:

```
g = give_gen(3)()
```

You *did* call `gen()`; had you referred to *just* `gen` without calling it you'd have a reference to that function.